# Group customer transactions based on the subsequent transaction

Tags: sql, oracle, teradatasql

Small change in the requirement

Needed Teradata SQL query to create a grouping from the first transaction to its subsequent transactions. If a subsequent transaction is made within 30 days of the previous transaction, consider them all to belongs to the same group. Break the group and start a new one if any transaction is made more than 30 days after the previous transaction.

data:

| trans_Id | customer_id | trans_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1101 | 2020-11-02 |
| 002 | 1101 | 2020-11-14 |
| 003 | 1101 | 2020-11-18 |
| 004 | 1101 | 2021-12-04 |
| 005 | 1101 | 2021-01-06 |
| 006 | 1101 | 2021-01-08 |
| 007 | 1101 | 2021-02-17 |
| 008 | 1101 | 2021-03-01 |
| 009 | 1101 | 2021-03-04 |
| 010 | 1102 | 2021-03-02 |
| 011 | 1102 | 2021-03-08 |
| 012 | 1102 | 2021-04-01 |
| 013 | 1102 | 2021-04-02 |
| 014 | 1102 | 2021-04-12 |
| 015 | 1102 | 2021-04-29 |
| 016 | 1102 | 2021-06-10 |
| 017 | 1102 | 2021-06-12 |

Expected result (expecting grouping like below).
from 001 till 004 fall under within 30 day to its previous transaction.
005 has elapsed 30 day from it's previous transaction so new group has to be started.

| trans_Id | customer_id | trans_date | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1101 | 2020-11-02 | 1 |
| 002 | 1101 | 2020-11-14 | 1 |
| 003 | 1101 | 2020-11-18 | 1 |
| 004 | 1101 | 2021-12-04 | 1 |
| 005 | 1101 | 2021-01-06 | 2 |
| 006 | 1101 | 2021-01-08 | 2 |
| 007 | 1101 | 2021-02-17 | 3 |
| 008 | 1101 | 2021-03-01 | 3 |
| 009 | 1101 | 2021-03-04 | 3 |
| 010 | 1102 | 2021-03-02 | 1 |
| 011 | 1102 | 2021-03-08 | 1 |
| 012 | 1102 | 2021-04-01 | 2 |
| 013 | 1102 | 2021-04-02 | 2 |
| 014 | 1102 | 2021-04-12 | 2 |
| 015 | 1102 | 2021-04-29 | 2 |
| 016 | 1102 | 2021-06-10 | 3 |
| 017 | 1102 | 2021-06-12 | 3 |

Comment: Is it Teradata or Oracle? can't be both, surely

Comment: Are the years in your sample data and expected results correct? Specifically, it looks like trans_ids 004 and 005 have the wrong years. And when you compare 006 to 005, you get a negative difference of over a year as well.

Comment: Corrected it. I am looking for solution in Teradata but sql also fine

Comment: Seems like gaps-and-islands type problem. If requirements change after an answer  is proposed, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY customer_id
  ORDER BY trans_date
  MEASURES
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS grp
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( within_30_days+ )
  DEFINE
    within_30_days AS trans_date <= FIRST(trans_date) + INTERVAL '30' DAY
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (trans_id, customer_id, trans_date) AS
  SELECT '001', '1101',  DATE '2020-11-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '002', '1101',  DATE '2020-11-14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '003', '1101',  DATE '2020-11-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '004', '1101',  DATE '2021-12-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '005', '1101',  DATE '2021-12-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '006', '1101',  DATE '2021-12-08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '007', '1101',  DATE '2021-01-17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '008', '1101',  DATE '2021-05-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '009', '1101',  DATE '2021-05-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '010', '1102',  DATE '2021-03-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '011', '1102',  DATE '2021-03-08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '012', '1102',  DATE '2021-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '013', '1102',  DATE '2021-04-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '014', '1102',  DATE '2021-04-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '015', '1102',  DATE '2021-04-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '016', '1102',  DATE '2021-06-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '017', '1102',  DATE '2021-06-12' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| CUSTOMER_ID | TRANS_DATE | GRP | TRANS_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1101 | 2020-11-02 00:00:00 | 1 | 001 |
| 1101 | 2020-11-14 00:00:00 | 1 | 002 |
| 1101 | 2020-11-18 00:00:00 | 1 | 003 |
| 1101 | 2021-01-17 00:00:00 | 2 | 007 |
| 1101 | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 | 3 | 008 |
| 1101 | 2021-05-04 00:00:00 | 3 | 009 |
| 1101 | 2021-12-04 00:00:00 | 4 | 004 |
| 1101 | 2021-12-05 00:00:00 | 4 | 005 |
| 1101 | 2021-12-08 00:00:00 | 4 | 006 |
| 1102 | 2021-03-02 00:00:00 | 1 | 010 |
| 1102 | 2021-03-08 00:00:00 | 1 | 011 |
| 1102 | 2021-04-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 012 |
| 1102 | 2021-04-02 00:00:00 | 2 | 013 |
| 1102 | 2021-04-12 00:00:00 | 2 | 014 |
| 1102 | 2021-04-29 00:00:00 | 2 | 015 |
| 1102 | 2021-06-10 00:00:00 | 3 | 016 |
| 1102 | 2021-06-12 00:00:00 | 3 | 017 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qftC_Ras)

Answer (score 1):

```
Other Way(ORACLE):
with jobdata as (
    select '001' as trans_Id,   '1101' as customer_id,  to_date('2020-11-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as trans_date from dual union all
    select '002' as trans_Id,   '1101' as customer_id,  to_date('2020-11-14', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as trans_date from dual  union all
    select '003' as trans_Id,   '1101' as customer_id,  to_date('2020-11-18', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as trans_date from dual  union all
    select '004' as trans_Id,   '1101' as customer_id,  to_date('2021-12-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as trans_date from dual  union all
    select '005' as trans_Id,   '1101' as customer_id,  to_date('2021-12-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as trans_date from dual  union all
    select '006' as trans_Id,   '1101' as customer_id,  to_date('2021-12-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as trans_date from dual  union all
    select '007' as trans_Id,   '1101' as customer_id,  to_date('2021-01-17', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as trans_date from dual  union all
    select '008' as trans_Id,   '1101' as customer_id,  to_date('2021-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as trans_date from dual  union all
    select '009' as trans_Id,   '1101' as customer_id,  to_date('2021-05-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as trans_date from dual  union all
    select '010' as trans_Id,   '1102' as customer_id,  to_date('2021-03-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as trans_date from dual  union all
    select '011' as trans_Id,   '1102' as customer_id,  to_date('2021-03-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as trans_date from dual  union all
    select '012' as trans_Id,   '1102' as customer_id,  to_date('2021-04-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as trans_date from dual  union all
    select '013' as trans_Id,   '1102' as customer_id,  to_date('2021-04-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as trans_date from dual  union all
    select '014' as trans_Id,   '1102' as customer_id,  to_date('2021-04-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as trans_date from dual  union all
    select '015' as trans_Id,   '1102' as customer_id,  to_date('2021-04-29', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as trans_date from dual  union all
    select '016' as trans_Id,   '1102' as customer_id,  to_date('2021-06-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as trans_date from dual  union all
    select '017' as trans_Id,   '1102' as customer_id,  to_date('2021-06-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as trans_date from dual 
)
select a.trans_Id, a.customer_id, a.trans_date 
    , dense_rank() over (partition by a.customer_id order by gap_group) as group_id
from (
    select a.*, min(a.trans_date) over (partition by a.customer_id order by customer_id, trans_date) as min_trans_date
        , a.trans_date - min(a.trans_date) over (partition by a.customer_id order by customer_id, trans_date) as gap_day
        , trunc((a.trans_date - min(a.trans_date) over (partition by a.customer_id order by customer_id, trans_date)) / 30) + 1 as gap_group
    from jobdata a
) a       
;
```

Comment: It is working as expected but small change in the requirement, now need to consider 30 day window from previous transaction.